# Wacom Intuos 4, Ubuntu 19.04 Studio, Krita ... POOF! go segfault

Tags: 19.04, wacom, wayland, krita

Trying to use an old Intuos 4 Wacom tablet on Ubuntu 19.04 Studio. Needless to say, this hardware works fine on Win10 and MacOS. Not so here. Krita just plain crashes. See Syslog:

> May 21 23:01:51 Heller org.kde.krita.desktop[3361]: krita.lib.flake:
>   "InteractionTool" : action "object_order_raise" conflicts with canvas
>   action "rotate_canvas_right" shortcut: "Ctrl+]" May 21 23:01:51 Heller
>   org.kde.krita.desktop[3361]: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to
>   QWidget "", which already has a layout May 21 23:01:53 Heller
>   org.kde.krita.desktop[3361]: free(): double free detected in tcache 2

After krita tried to double free, it segfaulted and closed.

This happens again and again. If I rmmod the wacom driver, Krita works as expected. Pull out the usb cable and reinsert it to load the driver, crash again.

I'd say this is likely upstream from Krita. Somewhere between Wayland and X input. Gimp doesn't much like using the tablet either.

Suggestions?

Comment: That's worth a shot. --NOPE. Same problem using an X Server.

Answer (score 0):

[Seems to be this bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72488). Someone [implemented a fix](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/248154), but the reviewers don't seem to be sure about it, and there's been no updates since January.

Krita [claims to have implemented a workaround](https://krita.org/en/item/krita-4-1-7-released/), but I'm using that version and still seeing the error. As expected, the AppImage build works properly, because it includes an older version of Qt.